# Copying and appending Strings to json file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have list of json files as below:
[image]

At the moment, T.json file is empty. All the other files already have some text. What I need is to create something like this:

1.At the beginning of the T.json file add sth like

```
{
  "T": [
```

2.Copy text from e.g. T_Average.json and T_Easy.json to T.json file

3.At the end of T.json file add this:

]
}

So at the end of program execution I need to have in my T.json sth like:

```
    {
      "T": [
             text from T_Average.json 
             text from T_Easy.json
      ]
    }
```

So how can I add text from 1st and 3rd step to the file?
And how can I copy everything from other files to T.json file?

I have already tried some solutions like this:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("T.json", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
{
    out.println("the text");
    out.println("more text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```

or like this one:

```
try {
    String data = " This is new content";
    File file = new File(FILENAME);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(data);
    System.out.println("Done");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but all the time, after line with `fw = new FileWriter()` it was jumping right to the catch clause.

So one more time:
How can I add text from 1st and 3rd step to the file?
And how can I copy everything from other files to T.json file?
Thanks :)

Comment: At runtime you cannot add data to files in assets as all in assets is read only.

Comment: The Assets folder is a build-time resource that is read-only for the Application. Once the files are specified in the APK, they cannot be changed at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Try

**1.** Add following methods `getJsonFromAssetFile` and `writeFile` to your code

**2.** Read json file

```
String content = getJsonFromAssetFile("T_Difficult.json");
```

**3** Create final json (as mentioned)

```
JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject();

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

        finalJson.put("T", jsonArray);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**4.** Write final json to file

```
writeFile(finalJson.toString().getBytes());
```

**writeFile**

```
public static void writeFile(byte[] data, File file) throws IOException {

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bos.write(data);
    }
    finally {
        if (bos != null) {
            try {
                bos.flush ();
                bos.close ();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**getJsonFromAssetFile**

```
public static String getJsonFromAssetFile(Context context, String jsonFileName) {

    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(jsonFileName);

        int size = is.available ();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read (buffer);

        is.close ();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

NOTE: Read json asset file using `getJsonFromAssetFile` method and Write file on internal/external storage and provide proper path to `writeFile` method

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added:  `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\y50-70\\Desktop\\T2\\app\\src\\main\\assets\\T.json");` and I called writeFile method with `writeFile(finalJson.toString().getBytes(), file);`, 
Unfortunately, it jumps to finally clause right after `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);`. Do you know what may be the reason for that?
BTW I have no idea what is `ServiceConstants.ENCODING`. What is that? And how can I import it?

Comment: @Tomas
Don't mention path "C:\\Users\\y50-70\\Desktop\\T2\\app\\src\\main\\assets‌​\\

Comment: Just use String content = getJsonFromAssetFile("T.json"); No need to mention path, you are running on android phone, not on desktop computer

Comment: Following the steps I have mentioned

Comment: @Pehlaj what is  ServiceConstants.ENCODING ?

Comment: @Ast, It is UTF-8 I believe

Comment: than maybe for a better comprehension of other users you could write:
String json = new String(buffer, "UTF8");